# How to remove CDATA from XML in Java and do some conversion?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying create Java Servlet which will modify existing XML.

This a part of my orginal XML:

```
<customfieldvalues>
<div id="errorDiv" style="display:none;"/>
<![CDATA[ 
 Vinduer, dører
 ]]>
</customfieldvalues>
```

I want to get the following result:

```
<customfieldvalues>
<div id="errorDiv" style="display:none;"/>
Vinduer, d&#248;rer
</customfieldvalues>
```

I iterate over the XML structure with:

```
Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("customfieldvalues");
for (int i=0; i<descNodes.getLength();i++) {
    Node node = descNodes.item(i);
    // how to ?
}
```

So, I need to remove `CDATA` and convert the content.
I saw that I can use [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) for the conversion.

Comment: This is has a partial answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067116/convert-an-xml-element-whose-content-is-inside-cdata

Answer (score 1):

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setCoalescing API

- Specifies that the parser produced by this code will
- convert CDATA nodes to Text nodes and append it to the
- adjacent (if any) text node. By default the value of this is set to
- `false`