# How to display description as HTML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to style an RSS document containing a description with HTML. I am unable to display this HTML using XSLT, in the Firefox browser.

This is the XML document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/rss.xsl' media='all' ?>
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[<p>This is the description</p>]]>
            </description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I've tried this XSLT command, but it shows the HTML:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="description"/></li>
```

This didn't work either:

```
<xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: Please add closing for cdata section like <![CDATA[<p>This is the description</p>]]> in your input xml

Comment: @imran Good call, fixed it in above example, but problem remains.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of output you expect. Keep in mind that the content of `description` is **not** HTML. It is a string equivalent to escaped HTML. --- Also, "didn't work" is not a useful description. Tell us what the actual result was - and what exactly did you use to get it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I want the HTML to be interpreted. So <b>string</b> would show as bold.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Are you staying I should remove <![CDATA[]]> to display HTML?

Comment: I am saying that if your data provider wants you to interpret the contents as HTML code, then they should not put it inside a CDATA section. -- And I am also saying you need to explain what your environment is. The result of an XSL transformation is a plain-text document. Nothing shows as bold in a plain-text document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Environment: Firefox browser reading XML and applying XLS.

Comment: AFAIK, Firefox does not do `disable-output-escaping`. See (for example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086755/parse-html-inside-the-cdata-text

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's the problem I am reporting :) How to solve it?