# Transform XML from CDATA using XSL

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I have this XML document:

```
<ns0:getDataResponse xmlns:ns0="http://abc.com/">
    <return>
        <wrapper>
            <data><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                            <ConDic>
                            <dictionary>bank</dictionary>
                                <rows>
                                    <row>
                                      <bic>ABKZKZKX</bic>
                                      <bcode>319</bcode>
                                      <name1>AA &quot;A BANK&quot;</namekz>
                                      <name2>BB &quot;B BANK&quot;</nameru>
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                      <bic>ABNAKZKX</bic>
                                      <bcode>922</bcode>
                                      <name1>CC &quot;C BANK&quot;</namekz>
                                      <name2>DD &quot;D BANK&quot;</nameru>
                                    </row>
                                </rows>
                            </ConDic>]]></data>
        </wrapper>
    </return>
</ns0:getDataResponse>
```

How I can parse it with XSL to get each rows in CDATA to make this kind of select:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://abc.com/">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
<xsl:template match="ns0:rows">

<select name="bank" id="bank" class="input" style="width: 370px;">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:sort select="name1"/>
        <option value="{bic}"><xsl:value-of select="name1" /></option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? You need an XSLT 3.0 processor with the 3.0 function http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-xpath-functions-30-20130108/#func-parse-xml or you need an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor supporting an extension function like http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse.

Comment: That escaped markup is not valid XML. There is no entity `&quot;` defined and there is no DTD references. Even if you used a first pass transform to extract the CDATA with disable-output-escaping, you would be left with invalid markup that won't parse as XML. Plus, it includes the XML declaration, which makes it more difficult to add a DTD reference in the DOE transform. Is there any way to get the producer of the webservice to change their output?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent defines `quot` so there does not have to be a DTD to define it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I think you should put your comment into an answer, so that this question is no longer in the "unanswered" category.

Comment: @Yoldar-Zi, does my comment help? Can you use a processor providing such an extension or providing XSLT 3.0 support?

Comment: @LarsH, I have asked the poster whether my comment helped, if he comes back I will move the suggestion into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment, I post a solution. The example use XSLT 3.0 with Saxon 9.5 (needs PE or EE version):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns0="http://abc.com/"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math ns0"
    version="3.0">


    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:getDataResponse">

        <select name="bank" id="bank" class="input" style="width: 370px;">
            <xsl:for-each select="parse-xml(return/wrapper/data)//row">
                <xsl:sort select="name1"/>
                <option value="{bic}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name1"/>
                </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With an input of

```
<ns0:getDataResponse xmlns:ns0="http://abc.com/">
    <return>
        <wrapper>
            <data><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                            <ConDic>
                            <dictionary>bank</dictionary>
                                <rows>
                                    <row>
                                      <bic>ABKZKZKX</bic>
                                      <bcode>319</bcode>
                                      <name1>AA &quot;A BANK&quot;</name1>
                                      <name2>BB &quot;B BANK&quot;</name2>
                                    </row>
                                    <row>
                                      <bic>ABNAKZKX</bic>
                                      <bcode>922</bcode>
                                      <name1>CC &quot;C BANK&quot;</name1>
                                      <name2>DD &quot;D BANK&quot;</name2>
                                    </row>
                                </rows>
                            </ConDic>]]></data>
        </wrapper>
    </return>
</ns0:getDataResponse>
```

the result is

```
<select name="bank" id="bank" class="input" style="width: 370px;">
   <option value="ABKZKZKX">AA "A BANK"</option>
   <option value="ABNAKZKX">CC "C BANK"</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [exslt](http://exslt.org/) extensions available, you should be able to use [`exslt:node-set`](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) to create a variable of the contents. Try something like (untested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
   extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
   exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
   version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="inner" select="exsl:node-set(//data/text())" />
    <select name="bank" id="bank" class="input" style="width: 370px;">
        <xsl:for-each select="$inner//row">
            ...
        </xsl:for-each>
    </select>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The `node-set()` function takes a *result tree fragment* and converts it to a node-set. It won't take a string and parse it into a node-set. So at best, the value of `$inner` will just be a string, and you won't be able to select `$inner//row`.