# XSL replace between html tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to replace or remove certain strings between html tag in XML node eg:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[<p>TEXT[…]</p>
    <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://somelink">test test</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://somelink">TEXT2</a>.</p>
]]>
</description>
```

I would like to get rid of this second `<p>...</p>` tag section in node or better it will be to replace  with "MORE"

Comment: What version of XSLT?  What have you tried so far?  If you're using version 1.0 you can't do this in a single pass.  And since you're dealing with HTML you may not be able to trust that it would parse as valid XML anyway...

Comment: XSLT 1.0 unfortunately

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an xml element whose content is inside CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067116/convert-an-xml-element-whose-content-is-inside-cdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to get rid of this second `<p>`...`</p>` tag

There are no tags in CDATA sections; it's all one string of text. Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(description, '&lt;/p&gt;'), '&lt;p&gt;')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you that solve my problem. Also I was thinking to do it like this if its possible of coursein XSL 1.0. If CDATA section is seen as a string so maybe possible is to split the text  and  using  [&#8230;] as a separator. And then display only 1 array