# XSLT replace <p></p> with new lines in PDF via XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is it possible to replace the `<p></p>` string in XSL with a new line? I have some text with this tags in it and I want to replace them with a new line. And what if I want to add some spacing between the lines?

The transformation generates a PDF in the end.

Right now I tried with this, but with no result:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($db/content/text, '&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;', '&#10;')" />
```

Comment: Please show a minimal but complete XML input sample and the corresponding output you want to create, together with the type of output you want (plain text or XML or HTML).

Comment: How does `$db/content/text` look like exactly, is it `<content><text><p></p></text></content>` or `<content><text><![CDATA[<p></p>]]></text></content>`? And XSLT doesn't generate PDF directly, it usually generates XSL-FO. So show a minimal but complete input sample and the corresponding XSL-FO you want to generate or perhaps make it clear that the question is simply about what XSL-FO is needed to render a new line character as a line break.

Comment: It's `<content><text>Aliquam at euismod purus, et tincidunt turpis.<p></p>Sed vitae neque tempus, vulputate mi a, scelerisque metus.<p></p>Praesent quis hendrerit quam. </text></content>`

Comment: How do you "generate a pdf in the end"? Use xsl-fo/fop?

Comment: Yes, using Apache FOP.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to transform the `p` elements into `&#10;` characters and you want them to be rendered as line breaks in the PDF output generated from XSL-FO one way is to put the contents into an `fo:block` element with the attribute `linefeed-treatment="preserve"` I think, so with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and `<xsl:apply-templates select="$db/content/text"/>` where you currently have the `xsl:value-of` you should get the output

```
Aliquam at euismod purus, et tincidunt turpis.
Sed vitae neque tempus, vulputate mi a, scelerisque metus.
Praesent quis hendrerit quam.
```

for the sample `<content><text>Aliquam at euismod purus, et tincidunt turpis.<p></p>Sed vitae neque tempus, vulputate mi a, scelerisque metus.<p></p>Praesent quis hendrerit quam. </text></content>` you have shown in the comment.

There might be better and easier ways, in particular if you use XSLT 2.0 where you could use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="p">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::p)]"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: With the XSLT 2.0 solution, you could add properties to the `fo:block`, e.g., `space-before` and/or `space-after`, so that there's extra space between the lines where a `<p></p>` used to be.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote about replacing `<p>` tags, so I suppose that your source is HTML.

If the **output** text will be also HTML, then (I suppose) you actually want
for each `<p>` tag:

- print its text content,
- put a `<br/>` after it.

It is quite reasonable solution for the content of e.g. `<td>` or `<div>` tags.

You can get this effect using the following XSLT script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For the below input sample:

```
<div>
  <p>Abcd</p>
  <p>Efgh Abcd</p>
  <p>Xyz Efgh Abcd</p>
</div>
```

it gives the following result:

```
<div>
  Abcd<br/>
  Efgh Abcd<br/>
  Xyz Efgh Abcd<br/>
</div>
```

If your goal is to transform **only some** `<p>` tags (not all),
you must accordingly adjust the `match` attribute in the template.

Comment: From the problem description it rather looks like the <p> tags are to be found in the element content, probably a CDATA section, so `<xsl:template match="p">` won't work.

Comment: If the content in question is within CDATA section, then read the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067116/convert-an-xml-element-whose-content-is-inside-cdata

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm generating a PDF in the end. I've updated the post now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty `fo:block` to indicate the paragraph breaks:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block space-after="0.5em" />
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, if `text` really contains just text and `<p></p>`, then you can make each text node into a separate `fo:block` and drop the `p`:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/text()">
  <fo:block space-after="0.5em">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" />
```

If `text` contains text plus other elements besides `p`, then you're back to needing either my first solution or @martin-honnen's solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to replace the `<p></p>` string in XSL with a new line?

Yes, it is, but from the clarification you presented in comments, that's not what you actually want to do.

XSL operates on an input document model (more or less a DOM) to generate an output model of the same type.  It indeed can modify elements' text content, which is how I would ordinarily be inclined to interpret the word "string" in your question, but it's a bit clumsy there, especially at XSLT version 1.0.  That's an entirely different thing from transforming *elements*, however, which is what you seem actually to want to do.

> I have some text with this tags in it and I want to replace them with a new line.

No, you haven't, at least not from an XML (or HTML) perspective.  You have an element with mixed content -- both character data and child elements -- and you want to replace certain of the child elements.  In XSL, you would ordinarily do that via a template that matches the elements you want to transform.  For example,

```
<!-- matches `p` elements with no child nodes of any kind (and in particular
     with no text node children).  -->
<xsl:template match="p[not(node())]">
  <!-- the template body presents the replacement for the matched element:
       a text node containing a single newline -->
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want the transform to transform everything else to itself then you would want to also include an identity transform in your stylesheet.  Google can provide you many examples of how that looks in XSLT.

> And what if I want to add some spacing between the lines?

It depends on what that means, which is a function of the significance of the output document.  You can as easily transform `<p/>` elements to multiple newlines, or to `<br/>` elements, or to whatever you want.